# Jquery DIalog problems with overlay and position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm makeing a webpage that has a modal Jquery dialog. When the dialog opens everything seems fine until you start to scroll. If you scroll you see that the overlay doesnot cover the whole webpage only up to the point where the dialog is. And when i want to move the dialog, when i have scrolled the page, the dialog just jumps downward, so that the scrolld distance is the distance between mouse and dialog.

Anyone know how to fix these things ?

EDIT 1:
FIxed problem with overlay size.

```
.ui-widget-overlay {
    position:fixed;
}
```

Edit 2:
Some code

```
jQuery("#markusPopUp").dialog({
                    resizable: false,
                    height: 375,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        "Kinnita": function () {
                           //Some action
                        },
                        "Katkesta": function () {
                            jQuery(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                });

<div id="markusPopUp" style="display:none" title=" title">
    <div id="eelmised" style="word-wrap: break-word;"></div>
    <textarea id="markus"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to your code :

```
jQuery("#markusPopUp").dialog({
                    resizable: false,
                    height: 375,
 position: { my: "center", at: "center", of: window },
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        "Kinnita": function () {
                           //Some action
                        },
                        "Katkesta": function () {
                            jQuery(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                });
```